# Refresh an image inside a gridview with updatepanel (or other mean)

Tags: jquery, ajax, gridview, updatepanel, postback

I have a GridView in an ASP page (C#) which contains an image in each row. I want to simulate some kind of thumb-wheel with a couple of arrows allow the user to select the image of his choice from images stored in the server database. But I don't want to refresh the entire grid/page each time the user presses on the left or right arrow to see the next picture.
So far I have tried several options of UpdatePanel but I cannot have this only picture to be refreshed.
Just to give an idea, this is the markup. Any help appreciated.

```
<div style="width:1200px; height:900px; margin:0 auto;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server" >
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTextType" runat="server" Text="Text type"  style="z-index: 1; left: 422px; top: 200px; position: absolute; height: 25px; width: 126px; right: 1036px;" Font-Names="Verdana"></asp:Label>


        <asp:GridView ID="listText" runat="server"  style="z-index: 1; left: 566px; top: 284px; position: absolute; height: 160px; width: 397px; right: 621px;" Font-Names="Verdana"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="False" Font-Size="17pt">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="itm" SortExpression="Value">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemText" runat="server" OnTextChanged="OnTextChanged" Text='<%#Eval("text") %>'  AutoPostBack="True" BorderWidth="0" Width="385px" Font-Size="Medium" ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="leftArrow" SortExpression="Value">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="leftArrow" runat="server" OnClick="onLeftArrow"  Width="6px" ImageUrl="Images\LeftArrow.png" ></asp:ImageButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

<!-- The image to be refreshed each time an arrow is pressed -->
                    <asp:Image runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%#Eval("imagename") %>' ControlStyle-Height="35px" ControlStyle-Width="35px"></asp:Image>




            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RightArrow" SortExpression="Value">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="RightArrow" runat="server" OnClick="onRightArrow"  Width="6px" ImageUrl="Images\RightArrow.png" ></asp:ImageButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
            <RowStyle BorderStyle="None" Height="17px" Wrap="True" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It kooks like I solved it. I indeed got some improvements while still not what I expected but this is what I did. In the markup, I encapsulated bothe image and the arrows:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Command">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="gridUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="imagename" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%#Eval("imagename") %>' ControlStyle-Height="35px" ControlStyle-Width="35px"></asp:Image>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RightArrow" SortExpression="Value">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel_ra" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="RightArrow" runat="server" OnClick="onRightArrow"  Width="6px" ImageUrl="Images\RightArrow.png" ></asp:ImageButton>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

In the C# code, the only way to refresh the image was to access the arrow ID by finding its name inside the Grid row:

```
protected void onRightArrow(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton thisImage = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)thisImage.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
    string filenme = "somefilename.png";
    Control cc = currentRow.FindControl("imagename");
    if (cc != null)
    {
        Image imagename = (Image)cc;
        imagename.ImageUrl = filenme;
        //gridUpdatePanel
        Control upd = currentRow.FindControl("gridUpdatePanel");
        UpdatePanel updpnl = (UpdatePanel)upd;
        updpnl .Update();
    }
}
```